# Can't run command under /bin/false user

Tags: centos, tomcat, centos8, su

Centos 8.

There is `snowuser`:

```
[snowuser@snowcannon-01 ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep snowuser  
snowuser:x:1002:1002::/home/snowuser:/bin/bash   
[snowuser@snowcannon-01 ~]$ groups  
snowuser wheel
```

There is `tomcat` user:

```
[snowuser@snowcannon-01 ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep tomcat  
tomcat:x:1003:1003::/opt/tomcat:/bin/false  


cat /etc/group | grep "tomcat\|snowuser"  
wheel:x:10:ydyachuk,amsliusar,snowuser  
snowuser:x:1002:   
tomcat:x:1003:
```

Trying to run Tomcat's start script under `tomcat` user:

`/bin/su tomcat -c /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`

But got nothing meaning that neither any error message appeared nor Tomcat process was executed.

Only one detail I have is that command was being executed with errors:

```
[snowuser@snowcannon-01 ~]$ echo $?
1
```

Seems `tomcat` user has proper permissions for the script execution:

```
[snowuser@snowcannon-01 ~]$ ll /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 tomcat tomcat 1904 Nov 11 15:14 /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

How can I make Tomcat running?

Comment: How was Tomcat installed? If there's a Tomcat service it can be started with something like `systemctl start tomcat`.

Comment: I just downloaded Tomcat as tar.gz file, unpacked & copied files to /opt/tomcat folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the default shell to `/bin/false` means that `su` will switch user, and then execute

```
/bin/false -c /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

You can use the `-s` [option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) to `su` to override the setting in `/etc/passwd`, but this is only permitted if the calling user is root, or the existing entry in `/etc/passwd` is listed in `/etc/shells`.

Comment: Crazy note..... for my version of busybox, that last line is super important: `only permitted if ... the existing entry in /etc/passwd is listed in /etc/shells`. This _includes_ /bin/false. In other words, if your user account's shell is set to /bin/false, you can't su to it with the -s option unless you also place /bin/false into the /etc/shells file. Unexpected.

Comment: That is the same for any correct implementation of `su` -- if the login shell is set to `/bin/false`, it is supposed to be impossible to log in, but users should be allowed to use a different shell if they want, so there is a list of valid shells that users can use directly.